# Am I using Apache Camel aggregator correctly?

Tags: java, apache-camel, routes, aggregator, enterprise-integration

My *understanding* of a **route** (in Apache Camel verbiage) is that it represents a flow of data from one endpoint to another, and that it will stop at various **processors** along the way that perform EIP-type operations on the data.

If that's a correct/fair assessment of a route, then I am modeling a problem that I *believe* requires several routes inside the same `CamelContext` (I'm using a Spring):

1. Route 1: Extracts data from Source-1, processes it, converts it to a `List<SomePOJO>` and then sends it to an aggregator
2. Route 2: Extracts data from Source-2, processes it, also converts it to a `List<SomePOJO>` and then sends it to an aggregator
3. Route 3: Contains an aggregator that waits until it receives a `List<SomePOJO>` from **both** Route 1 and Route 2, and then continues processing an aggregated list

Here's the thing: **both `List<SomePOJO>`s need to arrive at the aggregator at the same time**, or rather, the aggregator bean has to *wait* until it's received data from both routes before it can aggregate the 2 lists into a single `List<SomePOJO>` and send the aggregated list off to the rest of Route 3.

So far I have the following pseudo-coded `<camelContext>`:

```
<camelContext id="my-routes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!-- Route 1 -->
    <route id="route-1">
        <from uri="time://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />

        <!-- Extracts data from Source 1, processes it, and then produces a List<SomePOJO>. -->
        <to uri="bean:extractor1?method=process" />

        <!-- Send to aggregator. -->
        <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
    </route>

    <!-- Route 2 -->
    <route id="route-2">
        <from uri="time://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />

        <!-- Extracts data from Source 2, processes it, and then produces a List<SomePOJO>. -->
        <to uri="bean:extractor2?method=process" />

        <!-- Send to aggregator. -->
        <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
    </route>

    <!-- Route 3 -->
    <route id="route-3">
        <from uri="direct:aggregator" />

        <aggregate strategyRef="listAggregatorStrategy">
            <correlationExpression>
                <!-- Haven't figured this part out yet. -->
            </correlationExpression>
            <to uri="bean:lastProcessor?method=process" />
        </aggregate>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="listAggregatorStrategy" class="com.myapp.ListAggregatorStrategy" />
```

Then in Java:

```
public class ListAggregatorStrategy implements AggregatoryStrategy {
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange exchange) {
        List<SomePOJO> route1POJOs = extractRoute1POJOs(exchange);
        List<SomePOJO> route2POJOs = extractRoute2POJOs(exchange);

        List<SomePOJO> aggregateList = new ArrayList<SomePOJO>(route1POJOs);
        aggregateList.addAll(route2POJOs);

        return aggregateList;
    }
}
```

#### My questions

1. Is my basic setup correct? In other words, am I using the `direct:aggregator` endpoint correctly to send data out of `route-1` and `route-2` and into `route-3`'s aggregator?
2. Will my aggregator work the way I am expecting it to here? Say the `extractor1` bean in `route-1` takes only 5 seconds to run, but the `extractor2` bean in `route-2` take 2 minutes to run. At t=5, the aggregator should receive the data from `extractor1` and start waiting (for 2 mins) until `extractor2` finishes and gives it the rest of the data to aggregate. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on the right track, the [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) page has a lot of good information about this.

The `<correlationExpression>` is the key to matching an Exchange from each route and **completionSize** can specify how many to wait for. In your case it looks like each route is only designed to run once, in which case the expression could be using a fixed header value from each Exchange, otherwise you would need something like a counter class for each route.

Here is an update to your example:

```
<route id="route-1">
    <from uri="time://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />
    <to uri="bean:extractor1?method=process" />
    <setHeader headerName="id">
        <constant>myHeaderValue</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
</route>

<route id="route-2">
    <from uri="time://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />
    <to uri="bean:extractor2?method=process" />
    <setHeader headerName="id">
        <constant>myHeaderValue</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="direct:aggregator" />
</route>

<route id="route-3">
    <from uri="direct:aggregator" />

    <aggregate strategyRef="listAggregatorStrategy" completionSize="2">
        <correlationExpression>
            <simple>header.id</simple>
        </correlationExpression>
        <to uri="bean:lastProcessor?method=process" />
    </aggregate>
</route>
```